# Persistent Spot Instance request for Defined Duration Spot Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to create a Pesistent Spot Instance request for a Defined Duration Spot Instances. Essentially I need Spot Instances that run for 6 hours and then terminate, and then a new Spot Instance be launched based on the Persistent Spot Instance request.

Is that possible through the console?

Comment: You can request a [specific duration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html), but there's no guarantee that you'll get an instance - though you probably will. You can try using a [spot fleet with a spot instance pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html) with a desired capacity of one. If you need this instance to be up at a specific time, you should use on-demand or reserved instances.

Comment: In addition to @Tim's comment, to terminate the instance at a specific time you can use [Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/).